# How to use SCSUDO to run scripts with positional parameters?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, sudo

I am trying to use `scsudo` to run a number of defined commands to stop and start processes on a UNIX host. The issue I am experiencing is that `scsudo` does not seem to like the use of positional parameters when script is called with `scsudo` from command configuration file.

I have been tasked with implementing `scsudo` to reduce the number of functional access requests to stop and start processes and other defined commands, and the administrative overhead associated with this.

Here is an example:

```
scsudo - <functional_id> "/opt/scripts/Start_Process_script.sh parameter1 parameter2 parameter3"
Password:
Reason:
execvp: No such file or directory
```

It looks like the scsudo configuration file does not seem to handle the parameters when calling script and so fails to find script it has been asked to run.

I have placed parentheses around command including parameters but this still has not resolved the problem?

I have searched the web and Stack Exchange thoroughly but have been unable to return much if anything related to `scsudo` in terms of guides or knowledge base for the use of `scsudo`.

I would be very grateful for your assistant on this matter.

Comment: I'm curious - Google is not showing me much about `scsudo`; can you say anything about where it comes from?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler `Scsudo` works in a simlar way to `sudo` providing user with functional account access for a specified group of users on a specified number of hosts to run a predefined number of commands. User, Host and Commands groups are created which contains who can run what commands on which hosts. `Scsudo` also provides an audit trail containing details of what commands were run, by whom and on which host. I have a better explanation at work, so may update this on my return.

Answer (score 3):

It's trivial when you know the trick:

```
scsudo - <functional_id> sh -c "/opt/scripts/Start_Process_script.sh parameter1 parameter2 parameter3"
```

You might also be able to use:

```
scsudo - <functional_id> /opt/scripts/Start_Process_script.sh parameter1 parameter2 parameter3
```

if the script starts with an appropriate shebang (`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` or whatever).

As you wrote it, the `scsudo` command is looking to execute a program in `/opt/scripts` called `"Start_Process_script.sh parameter1 parameter2 parameter3"` (complete with embedded spaces) and isn't finding it, hence the error.